# Flow with Rest Object in a functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I'm making a functional component that handle various properties and we can pass other basic properties to this component with Rest object.

The fact is i'm getting 2 Flow errors :

- Cannot create TouchableOpacity element because inexact props [1] is incompatible
  with exact Props [2].
- Cannot get props.style because property style is missing in rest of object
  pattern [1].

Here is my code :

```
type Props = {
  text: string,
  textColor: string,
  backgroundColor: string,
  handleClick: () => void,
};

const Button = ({
  textId,
  textColor,
  backgroundColor,
  handleClick,
  ...props
}: Props) => {
  const {t} = useTranslation();

  const styles = {
    button: {
      padding: 10,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    },
    text: {
      color: textColor,
      textAlign: 'center',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      {...props}
      style={[styles.button, props.style]}
      onPress={handleClick}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{t(textId)}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

How can i have a proper way to type my Rest Object ...props ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a type exact by doing the following :

```
type Props =  $Exact<{
  text: string,
  textColor: string,
  backgroundColor: string,
  handleClick: () => void,
}>;
```

That should solve your first error.

As for the second error I think adding `style` as a entry in your `Props` type should solve that.